# How can i show this Equality?

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a complete Riemannian manifold and $N\subset M$ a closed submanifold. If codimension of $N$ is $0$ take $q\in\partial N$ and $v\in T_qN$, where $\partial N$ is the boundary of $N$ as a subset of $M$ and if codimension of $N$ is bigger than $0$, take $q\in N$ and $v\in T_qN$. Let $\gamma:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\rightarrow M$ be a differentuable curve such that $\gamma(0)=q$ and $\gamma'(0)=v$. Let $d$ denote the geodesic distance in $M$.

How can one show that $d(\gamma(t),N)=o(t)$ for small $t$?

Thanks

Comment: If $M=\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\gamma$ is a line, then this is true. Thats the only thing i know @FlybyNight

Comment: Could you put this question into context please? There are some things that worry me. For example, the usual definition of a closed manifold is a compact manifold without boundary, so $\partial N = \emptyset$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_manifold

Comment: When i say $\partial N$, it is the boundary of $N$ as a subset of $M$. Im gonna edit it to make it clear.

Comment: This problem appear in trying to solve this problem: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/241461/geodesic-distance-from-point-to-manifold